Ping Federate Settings to configure authorization code grant flow using Postman
Can someone please provide Ping Federate settings to configure authorization code grant flow using OAuth2.0 and OIDC protocols from Postman.
This is my configuration in postman to make an authentication request and request a token from Ping Federate:
Auth URL: https://192.168.1.105:9031/as/authorization.oauth2
Access Token URL: https://192.168.1.105:9031/as/token.oauth2
Client ID:XXXX
Client Secret: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Scope: openid profile email (I've configured these as exclusive scopes in Ping Federate)
Client Authentication: Sent as Basic Auth Header

When I click on get new access token, I get a http 200 success. But I don't get the token from Ping in Postman.
This is server log captured in Ping Federate:

ERROR [org.sourceid.websso.profiles.ExceptionLoggingSupport] Exception occurred during request processing
org.sourceid.websso.profiles.ProcessRuntimeException: Authn Policy Tree resulted in no authentication source selection.

Can you please help troubleshoot. I am using the latest version of Ping Federate (v12.1)
